# Debugging with Events in Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, multithreading, visual-studio

If I create an event using `CreateEvent` in Windows, how can I check if that event is signaled or not using the debugger in Visual Studio?  `CreateEvent` returns back a handle, which doesn't give me access to much information.  Before I call `WaitForSingleObject()`, I want to check to see if the event is signaled before I step into the function.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Process Explorer tool (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to manually check the event outside of the debugger.  It helps if the event is named, so that you can find it easier.

Answer (score 4):

Use the handle command. Here is a sample

The following command displays detailed information about handle 0x8.

```
0:000> !handle 8 f
```

Handle 8
  Type          Event
  Attributes    0
  GrantedAccess 0x100003:
         Synch
         QueryState,ModifyState
  HandleCount   2
  PointerCount  3
  Name          
  Object Specific Information
    Event Type Auto Reset
    Event is Waiting

Comment: Note that this command is for Debugging Tools for Windows (WinDbg / ntsd / cdb / kd), not Visual Studio. DTW is at http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx

Comment: @bk1e: That's true. However, it's also [possible to use the Windows Debugger Engine from Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3438489/1889329), so the `!handle` extension command is available in Visual Studio as well.

Answer (score 1):

If the event is signaled and you use WaitForSingleObject(), it will return immediately.  Also, you can call WaitForSingleObject() with a wait time of 0 to determine if it is signaled or not.  However, that should not be necessary -- set the initial state in the CreateEvent() call (what has elapsed so far is unclear in your question).