# Switch Live Debugging Session From VStudio (2010) to WinDbg

Tags: c#, debugging, windbg, visual-studio-debugging

I suspect the answer is no, but maybe someone knows some magic.

I find VStudio to be easier to use to step through c# code.  However, when I encounter a crash in the (non-CLR) layers below the CLR layers, I'd like to be able to use WinDbg.  About the only thing I can think of is making a DMP file in VStudio and opening it in WinDbg.  The dump creation doesn't give a lot of options, though, and I suspect that I'll miss some debug info.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3438489/1888362

Comment: That link is about using SOS, which is a .NET extension to WinDbg, and not using WinDbg commands in VStudio.  I want to do normal unmanaged debugging in WinDbg.

Comment: The Windows Driver Kit (WDK) 8 is fully integrated with Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012, you can execute any WinDbg extentions and commands within VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio will do a full memory dump of the user memory as well as the thread info which is normally all you really need. Otherwise the only thing I know to do is to debug it under VS normally and then attach (non-invasively) with windbg. Unfortunately you can't step through code in windbg this way, but you can do most other things (inspect memory, dump the process, etc...)

Comment: If VS can `.detach` like Windbg can, then after attaching non-invasively with windbg, `.detach` VS, then attach invasively with a second instance of windbg. That second instance should be able to step.