# How to debug if windows event object is set or not?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

When using the visual studio debugger, I've got a the value for a HANDLE to a windows event synchronization object. Is it possible to tell (and ideally set up a watch) that shows whether the event is set or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible using the Visual Studio debugger. [WinDbg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063.aspx), on the other hand, offers the [!handle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563187.aspx) extension command. Passing a `0xf` UMFlags shows extensive information, including whether the event object is signaled. While it is possible to [use WinDbg from Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17278134/1889329), I found it somewhat tedious to do so.

Another option worth considering is setting a breakpoint on `ntdll.dll!NtSetEvent` (*Debug* -> *New Breakpoint* -> *Break at Function...*). Adding a condition (rightclicking the breakpoint -> *Condition...*) `@rax == <handle value>` will only break, if the parameter is the specific *`<handle value>`* you are interested in. This is for a 64-bit build. For a 32-bit build the condition would be `*((unsigned int*)(@esp+4)) == <handle value>`.

Setting up a breakpoint as outlined above has one - potentially significant - limitation: It will only get hit, if the event object is set from user mode code. If the event object gets signaled from kernel mode while servicing a user mode request, the breakpoint residing in user land won't get hit.

Answer (score 0):

probably off-topic; if you have a kernel debugger connection to the target, you can inspect event's DISPATCHER_HEADER::SignalState. nonzero likely means signaled. Why only likely? Because it is not documented.