# Is it possible to debug a binary-only process with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, windbg

Is it possible to debug a binary-only process for which I don't have any sources with Visual Studio in a way that I can have Debug breakpoints on entries of any loaded DLL ? Or do I have to use WinDbg for that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using windbg from Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438489/using-windbg-from-visual-studio)

Comment: Debug / Attach to process ... -> yes, it is possible.

Comment: That doesn't help me. I want to do the whole debugging from Visual Studio and I want to breakpoint DLL entry points from there.